# select first face OpenCV detectMultiScale with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm testing out OpenCV to detect faces and was wondering how can i effectively detect the first faces only?

the code below works for multiple but if I do a for loop on faces[0], the app complains with this:

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces[0]:
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable


if len(faces) == 0:
        print('the list is empty', datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    else:
        print('the list is NOT empty', 'Detected',len(faces),'Face(s)')
        print(faces)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
            roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]  

    cv.imshow('Facial Recognition', img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faces[0] is only one face so you cannot loop over it.

```
if len(faces) == 0:
    print('the list is empty', datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
else:
    print('the list is NOT empty', 'Detected',len(faces),'Face(s)')
    print(faces)

    face = faces[0]
    (x,y,w,h) = face 
    cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]  

cv.imshow('Facial Recognition', img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate faces[0] cause it is not array it will be a single value you just iterate the loop once and break at the end to display only the first face detected